# Installing Make in Cygwin

Tags: windows, installation, cygwin, automake

I am trying to build a Linux project in windows 7 environment usign cygwin. However I am continuously getting below error while configuring `make` for cygwin installation.

```
-bash: make: command not found
```

After searching on inernet the only solution is re running of setup and installed `make` package. I have installed automake1.15 but it is in `noarch` folder and there is no binary `make.exe` in bin folder.

Comment: You must install *make* **not** *automake* from *Cygwin* setup.

Comment: You can install both, but please use [apt-cyg](https://github.com/kou1okada/apt-cyg) with `apt-cyg install make automake` to make your Cygwin life a lot easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a **big** difference between the 2:

- [[GNU]: Automake](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake) - Generates *Makefile* templates
- [[GNU]: GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make) - Builds software from sources (via *Makefile*s)

So you need to select ***Make*** from *Cygwin* setup.

**Notes**:

- *Automake* (or any package, as a matter of fact) is downloaded in the *noarch* *dir*, when it's compatible with any *OS* (*Cygwin*, in this case) architecture (*32 bit* and *64 bit* (currently)), meaning that it doesn't contain binaries (*.exe*s, *.dll*s (*.so*s)), only script-like files
- *Make* on the other hand, **does** contain binaries (*/usr/bin/make* itself it is a binary) and will be downloaded in the appropriate *dir* (*x86_64* or *x86*)
- The ***download*** *dir* **is not the same thing as** the ***installation*** *dir* (there may be more than one, and it's under *Cygwin* installation *dir*)

For more (generic) details, check [[Cygwin]: Installing and Updating Cygwin Packages](https://cygwin.com/install.html).

[[Cygwin]: Cygwin FAQ - Does the Cygwin Setup program accept command-line arguments?](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.cli) might also be a good starting point for command line options (check [[SO]: Installing Make in Cygwin (@PJain's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54587426/installing-make-in-cygwin/54607858#54607858)).

**Final note**: *Cygwin* is kind of obsolete. Switch to *WSL(**2**)*, which runs a real *Ubuntu* (no wrappers / adapters) as a *VM* (in *Hyper-V* - which runs at a totally different level).

Answer (score 10):

run command `setup-x86_64.exe -q --packages=make`(because make is not installed) in command prompt where the setup-x86_64.exe file is available